# Loopback default find method does not support large where condition data

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Loopback default find method does not support large where condition data due to method type GET.

I am filtering list with where condition which have large array of ids. And default find method for collection not work for it. Client side i have using angularjs.

What should i do either create a POST API for find request or their are another way to handle this.

Comment: You should give us more info, but maybe you can do the filtering client side.

Comment: A GET API have limit to pass data on it so default find api of loopback has type GET. how can i send large data on this API for filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted here, [nodeJS max header size in http.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167656/nodejs-max-header-size-in-http-request)

it is not a loopback issue. Http does not define any limit, but servers usually accept 8kb or 16kb headers size and you cannot alter this on node unless you compile you own version. Making your own custom method passing your data to the body of the request will work.

Comment: But this is not a good approach to make custom API for all collection.

Comment: Well obviously you cannot pass so many data to the headers. Maybe your filtering needs another approach. You could create groups and add ids there and filter by groups. The case that you need to pass so many ids to the filter probably is bad design.