# How to fix 431 Request Header Fields Too Large in React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, http-headers, request-headers

I'm working through a MERN sign up/login auth tutorial on youtube that uses Redux. When attempting to POST a test user to the server in Postman, I receive the 431 header request is too large error response.

I've read in some places that clearing the cache/history in your browser works, so I've tried that to no avail. I've also added in a "Clear-Site-Data": "*" entry to the header request (in addition to "Content-Type": "application/json") which hasn't worked, either.

Client Side Code for Sign Up

```
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, password } = this.state;

    const newUser = {
      name,
      email,
      password
    };

    this.props.register(newUser);
  };

//redux actions
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => dispatch => {

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Clear-Site-Data": "*"
    }
  };

  // Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

  axios
    .post('/api/users', body, config)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL')
      );
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

The user sign up should be sending a name, email and password to my connected Mongo db, however, it halts me and redux hits the REGISTER_FAIL type I created returning the 431 error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the server that you are using? Is your express server sitting behind an nginx? What express middleware are you using? Also, providing the actual HTTP request would be pretty useful.

Answer (score 22):

I had faced the same issue in my Angular Application. After spending a lot of time, I had found out that the issue is related to Node.js.

We were using Node.js `v12.x.x`, and in this version, `max-http-header-size` was reduced to `8KB` from `80KB`. And the auth token which I had was around `10KB`. That's why, when I reload the app, the browser starts giving `431 request header fields too large` error for some of the files.

I updated the Node.js to `v14.x.x`, and it started working again because, in `v14.0.0`, `max-http-header-size` has been increased to `16KB`.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: The site would work for me in incognito mode so I figured this solution might work and it did

Answer (score 15):

Another suggestion would be to access your cookies, in the inspector tool, and delete. applicable cookies for your `localhost:{port}` application.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problems with just using localhost(not limited to redux). Maybe this might help. 
Put this into url: chrome://settings/?search=cache

Click on Clear Browsing data.

 
Tick cookies and other site data (Important since cookies is in HTTP header)
TIck cached images and files (might be optional)

Answer (score 8):

Not reactjs, but using **vue-cli**, for people like me, just being stupid it may help:

I started my Vue app on port `8080`, and my local backend was running at port `4000`. However my requests pointed to `8080` and the response I got from Webpack Serving was "431 Request Header Fields Too Large".

The plain solution was just to use the right backend-port. Even though that was a really stupid mistake of me, the error message is kinda useless here.

Answer (score 3):

It means you are trying to do this fetch on your current front-end development server. You need to specifiy the server address. For example:

`.post('/api/users', body, config)`

should read

```
.post('http://localhost:4000/api/users', body, config)
```

Another fix would be to change the line `proxy` in your `package.json` from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:4000` assuming that 4000 is your actual server port.

Comment: The Proxy solution is what worked for me; my dataProvider.js in React was accessing my back-end port directly without the proxy, generating this 431 error.  Changing it to access '/api' instead of 'localhost:3000/api', and putting the proxy into the front-end package.json did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having is that I was trying to access a file in the `src` directory. The fix is to move it to the `public` directory and it now works fine.

E.g.
From

```
public
 - index.html
 - favicon.ico
 - etc
src
 > access-me
 - App.tsx
 - etc
```

to

```
public
 > access-me
 - index.html
 - favicon.ico
 - etc
src
 - App.tsx
 - etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it from Brad Travery's course? Check "proxy" in `package.json`, or try using full url in axios request. I had to completely restart server after changes, bc it's still use the old port (btw, I was enter wrong port)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351573/9285308

(the max http header size parameter is configurable):

```sh
node --max-http-header-size 16000 client.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In my react app, I add --max_old_space_size flag and it is worked. Current start script is :

```
"start": "react-scripts --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=12000 start",
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution:

NETCORE 6.0 / React template VS 2022

You have to setup the proxy url in package.json with the value of your url asp net application!
[AspNet URL in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wa6.png)

So you can have that 431 error when you use the proxy of default React/AspNetCore project and you don't setup a proxy url (or a valid one) in the package.json.

[proxy url in package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipHQK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your start script in **package.json** file and you are good to go.

```
"start": "react-scripts --max-http-header-size=1024 start",
```

Answer (score 0):

NextJS solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136780/6725458

```
"dev": "concurrently next dev node --max-http-header-size=64555 api-server"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I accidentally created a proxy to the frontend itself by mixing up the port.

I had a backend on port 5000 and create-react-app on port 3000.

I put

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
```

in the `package.json`. This is clearly a mistake as it leads to infinite recursion by querying the react app over and over.

I fixed it (obviously) by putting the correct port number

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Port numbers in your particular case might vary of course, just put this answer here for completess sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **NEXT.js** you can pass node arguments directly to next commands in **package.json**/**cli**

```json
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-http-header-size=12800000' next dev"
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli