# React Application Error 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) in twilio Video chat Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, twilio-programmable-chat, videochat

I am facing Status Code: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large in React Twilio Project, is the reason is video chat for large headers or any other?

Answer (score 0):

For me,
I have to set the proxy url value in my package.json with my backend url.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400740/13155486

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30618723)