# how to fix (Request Header Fields Too Large) in React Js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, request, http-headers

I am creating react js and laravel project and I display 3D model from database.

```
    <model-viewer bounds="tight" src={`http://localhost:8000/${item.pimage}`} 
ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" 
camera-controls environment-image="neutral"
 poster="poster.webp" shadow-intensity="1" 
camera-orbit="-7.313deg 27.56deg auto" width="60px" className="model"></model-viewer>
```

Error:
GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/products/1640341595.glb 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)
GET http://localhost:3000/admin/poster.webp 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Ho fix this Request Header Fields Too Large error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 431 Request Header Fields Too Large in React-Redux app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431355/how-to-fix-431-request-header-fields-too-large-in-react-redux-app)

Comment: [nodeJS max header size in http.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167656/nodejs-max-header-size-in-http-request/56351573#56351573)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I checked those .but I did not clear solutions

Comment: Did you find out issue is with ```laravel``` or ```nodejs```

Comment: I think the issue with React Js front end. I do not know why that error is shown.

Comment: I think the error is the refer link , Do you know how to change document.referrer manually?