# IdentityServer External auth provider - auth-callback - Redirection - 400 Bad request

Tags: angular, single-page-application, identityserver4, aspnetboilerplate, oidc-client

I am following
https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client and https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/Migrating-oidc-client-js-to-use-the-OpenID-Connect-Authorization-Code-Flow-and-PKCE to implement OIDC in SPA(Angular)

I am using aspboilerplate integrated IdentityServer

I've set up everything as per the above articles and I was able to navigate to external auth provider and was also able to enter the required credentials.

While redirecting to angular I am getting 400 - Bad request.  Here are the details

**Call back URL :**

```
http://localhost:4200/auth-callback?code=b74f38054d4becadaa3c45ce58a83c892e0d25e7fc4bfcc1ef29ce369b477596&scope=openid%20profile%20api1&state=18af0415b22b4614882d3e31113e2717&session_state=yP4rCdCetarKTsX6X0JXYTeV_1Xo8dud9V2FnT-14QE.db913b7a39e26220d8ac07de5a523eb2
```

**Cookies :**
Request sent 9095 bytes of Cookie data:

> ```
>   .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xkdte50z5pg=CfDJ8FAKJpEizERFtUzdjBClgctpGC-BWtg81DZ33kUapCDBb84U7ILfbqhExQzI3oVOWReKh72cV8hdROZcCh6wK7tbwl14PnWzNIECZGxyYx-K3MINQnZEp3cp-Ury1Z4KaRHs7mqvmf6oc30h6Q-oFxI
>   idsrv.external=chunks-2
>   idsrv.externalC1=CfDJ8FAKJpEizERFtUzdjBClgcum3jNb_Pj5sm5cfWLtKGcBqkU1VIUHlMdupOgnYwqTNw3bjxOoeVbCR1YR9y6Y2Q6zZvxX2juNv1iiUTwVIcTAG99R0QU8Ki1EJ8uOvaVN-BgUFNXYzcrct69nxfTGj5Ay2wL18-ziLczxnqurAbgTVkgyZs6IWHgtbOwyoyJb3klbQUkt4nmNZbwNSzeYknhDq7ohwEqeva51TIw73lciD2bJpJZnxUFx9eRI7FiJcf6qM3iYzvQ9R1-IRAmTleGEul_KY0eEcf8srxjPDgCRvj_Chy14N0rJdvWvrgio2yfdKTiCam2y-xPporU1oBOupt4zuaKsnPlHzzY9NksO_Gp7TTXJi91d3P2rl9FtBbQVQQDgpuNlwKO_WWIbd_nvcns647_0Cm0-mXiPecFrCC_plifOJ3ZRQHDYd-_ykOR_8WtGVYNigh0LPn4WxHoWJujUneRVaF_ootP4I1-uzcP6oDtTdxzCBgQpsujS_gRsHzZQ4S_EUX90R_BNEfWpg9Z5je0sT4Rma_tBeDBTCtqaZEKng_n4ybbn8xZc0dwuuGsVjYDSLXXoHLhQ55MalqJmRITH2mBNl89on3l2Y_e3_N-T_ScBJOS6HUHhTbKgiA2-R3XP5T_Gd0Fbmhpyrb4uqRJDybQb3muaKwYAJg51PSoiicA927KTcfiVPUzHY7YoENJ8MqBHkonvpjw9QtrWCgn0t4wTgrj_jIkIg9VmIZFReWGDiIw1cQnvA8u0lnPdxXl0D0ywm1eKCcvliHuFiT4KM2nKhUtlg75X5w5AYBFRb8ocx6Gx4zNEuV6cXzsx0-PVkbm7DllcMu3gMchpk47rDrIUjTDqlSjnlM1JaRWbrxXAui5tvZwOdAlI3e3__RIu-hdSJNO_ZgvPkLRUBiv0weNmsUWPjLzSjP8RVj-fWWCj1DuXSeUKcWTeEiXu019Klco48i1eUKB-vqLsUZHWAc8E02A8xF3kyz8OXOIam4tOlBD03-CgUK8zf0ahdtFegsXspJ75Z7Swml8CHpPkHrdZvGrryd-UbRipNpejtde1B9-WnLhpLQjXYCZdCOFndeg9CG1L9uBpaAU9pOB-AzmLqNIa1zi5qS0h9YqlL4wHGnK0iDlSmmK9kpZuTUS2nSEqs9hDwew1asxl7LPF1sMJyhjfDBAOmcHV4kZA_E6w0Y8_JQC4vu8Oda7vVoApvolhhHPqXpmmwbHxwxv1HjmC1UBdGUOJyn1rX6ASFJnEu1mmgqD1mgXizbmPzJd_KzRUkd5F7M0DcTBX3U3_p337g3QG5WJlBE5v_2JBlh6s-G5Lxs7UNXwcEigg6amJEgcIejNKXRbynJ-IKE41kd9PvXeG29d9B27Y37LPQu0xVaH7C7Z46pkASHZVrcPGLOoN0gHBTNwGaDUfca8Sb2bq3umhNjzK5uNxLaEZErCmjQQzUidKHcbWyuHC0ht0X1phOJv6hMTiUroYVaTP-ma_B350Z0euJq4atEPu59-Redz56aYtuKBW13axJs8qtsvXolwkGGboHzB-gj8PjDrT-iHGVMnoXVLkkOM_nYzfY5PwnaSWUdPtXnI6hxTlJomU5Bvhm-7TKLfB4bl3Fel4MM0QdrTQJz28FBTVFizzdksoPB4N_3jfSZsR373mN0wdtqpEjmKNUvGnVNX5wTc_3oMTO0cprxSVXwUK23phkomKHUYMZ8i11Z7T1mZHx5Yci1CMp-mHqTD-fBbmSK7YYvwtsSLeeI7u4cH-IYRl_3YQtxrFLwqTOzWllcz_JgbvwNXPYirLj0EVqGwttipg8QIuNyJIaPAnovTpJVI15ioJKfS9F9xlx-JVETbgxK3Py259pbTu8r-jHEZT0YdlItIZO-t5FM6hlTHAtQ2SuY8kdFQyBlUNZQPpw3ft6cz6mUt-2CcTdZ-xibkEdr7dEAZflSIrhL3Kt4lrdNalI5j68zG_0g9qfcXKTaqyMN0bawAzBfmaWAIp-u1KZb5vi6Kwf9ZEcNYF4fzHjHIOSNmySgiaYt2zH8EvbcJbTQmfBhuLOG6zBDU1-fDTK4-eBPkRJWEh4OTHm0jC8GV_N-80CrbUxjJUzoBWJXReu-sE00d4zBVHTHNJDlShXlyUPb_vqaGCJDFIlEEZUjyvAdwP0eOOeuhSz6jYicK9WwaZgsoLLsyeNZwLEOLftEBAax5ddoUdwe2kwxJ9eMZd_TE4YYzI9ZI37QAjzfhf573n8l2V--UEr-Kt6asTxzNvg1gK7doRns66W7KC6qnL_9ApLeoZ-hOX2QZ2J32D78mk5h4Dtv06lsNm4pBs8855PeZ7ygBu-p1edi1UjEWLzIxHxQ8YNNErP-U75HDgStXVRBY7CuXqz8RVc62Pjrj6z3Z98nV3KfcYJloq-Qejg1oSmFLgHrs5tTecL3caIopMy_MV0XRg6ly7cZtWq_8GQclQP_-6nTGy2ucN9ncj6sSjbFXxtKPV3bLAUm_JFtMfzzjR4TxP8s95zOiBwF5XXlLPu5QzBOoprI4Qf_XhmlTe8_1Z7X_HzCZSfWtgSDMEmcyOXxp4sPeKnh4U7o6ZlKukGz14F7gB94l0ZEHpbtOScRWb88o0fisHQv_G2Erslx3O5sGDMQG8G_W7d6IMBs1FFU1wcy8gmAznDbgFxtEPmXwdcoMY5MxliQQ8SrmREP_fU32jfGox5BiebA10BtQKjctJdnF_KPu3UzFuPGjFncCrpT74J3bR8O7BTUY175pOR2Vw4dtPCubHDeLHzFT8QWsPOO0CUS1kbtlooYbPS292E8lawWmYcFMcYsDq5x40NeX4-NVLuL0DvaqC_tgBLqvjDsrv6hQy6xQBoJt0PtfB-X0n38TCl9jwmpA3IiLR77FEAbpf0RRs4NB1_fIs9nSgK76JFPunxZ8jsgOW1ERNBTjgCaO72tct0l6rtrZAD35fu6KPBCFsofdoRpw5e5hxiq_Py2nYniCv6BkDLezt5wyYW83Zh8RJ1MQgZxNg3mJj0yvs0b3shdmxcjYZruCswCpcYHUCmqsTIjj4yQOHY15c8R50Asq4-eBuf3FhrIY7UWftvY3f3yL4IRQyX93oD0o1SCgpULpzR3dUAJD-QId3fHHbq-fC80Jqs09LP-HA9r7SutOSDpbcH-qD6ZDIVMddxGNOSyEVEN21fNPMUmVD-7u3-B9hmTrmb48HJLAQn9JjN7SdYjlNOoiyzwqZchnmWE3Twuro0S-GBryAqKdF7eQKpPqgtOks03JcXFERS0iRIJLZe3syjY39SZbhYMahkAc0D2TnJdUSxc-g85H_e0GobgE6R74fAwKeFDNrThwaULJBQTq0EWFikOMpZFzylfluw1M9U4ad-f53bYHPcvKFw8giZN6N-VM6qLrg3D3oU5169cXpmbRDeawreIOHvlVoIfhRZu7cSkARO0AGmL9XUrGivRNgMyDXRBIgIn_tbIPFvIrWkhgcZZZZP2t4YFzhn2MvKoHEFAfQHFFQ4jvCv-Waof19dRzbMSjS_Vz9qPzslbUjYATnIykQCeylOybDQKl5b6QVwmz9ioSl9OrJNFbzy9TDXSqjgCnefoHdZyVubpHSCADKJMB4FnLK5IdCFwcn2MSz_FuZzuCzDzR1B_WNTMuLQBR7Ks70uizUOJ8BKI7tuMO9nU9N6AQ7Preb_XRLVFJ31ISl5DvrQxyh__1Uet1IuT1vYrH4owFgaTnwOPRMPNxmnUTJRsbyEFdP6p6kQjV8zrId3qhBDIRMTfuOgT2n4awFqGbIM5DUnag003rbzpqD5zuL1RAlCfwyf2Yx0u0qY3es-zJV9CtlzU7X7YR-GBDSVJCKSqRRNg7YY-B2Y2E53Wudp6DDzVFuGs5G-XGJKzq3mru5h1CWaplCNgpDkdaRId-mfp1p2EP0vmoVkQnlkXqT0oJTsOBSTLKDrCfkniMbmKP_afqWS5jn6BmRDuFjEhdhl6Wa2GkMznTps_g9My
>   idsrv.externalC2=TudWp3eg3iUDnXn_uBCELCcSM1M6cxDlaF2RtsIFq74WusG6xZaIXZi033_2psAUpYZ-rKCn-fR-0p9RsHfw4Tot6oTODOcVUeF61Q3Zw6yoXZp497mMT3u-RMB58Yai5pUSMJk1Ex_2H1ekLjks9_ngpns76ARB3dWi_gzblCLQ-zSujcPw7ksoBLlt2X_h4B3w6Y91lCyHkn77NcAKdTiVgRs4-nX33NEr7Rogr3p365AV9vrJqWIl-eP7I0Di4mQn-EUZAd6C1iqBA-Af0wp3Nm2OmJJr-dEoPpppha7wW0_3IGk4_O_0cZjv5e0-63ER0X3cB5ZoKzRarKkdNEm3uBgcexGLOWJyTL8ntrXfytxxC0iP4DiO-wSnydrD0r-k6F9iLd_-pSuz30MnHDAAXn0141EC7gLr-J1EFS3ou2b8ocjIjJUF9jZ_V9IfibMrI_K7o4e-Yk5uhvjIzOq_usu2LgDhLjLIYXYwX_lQPX-D_z9Apn5IfE6iaGpc2ziqocj2uDFEA_j2dKtJBiyRylBcv89BJfWcsNHLybiB1dVBSFeRmQx_Bi24Hv0fkjw-7FLIFnGHv0UM2t09zp6QL4T9K7ggxOZMWp1-l4yIfnJRBDOVzSUcJZLEmAzv-lFcppUOtvrUmERDHItWFI2IF56flIGH5bLv7FJBFCW8Ke4HcI70EiWwBSHvO6JionGOrXpsAmVGW3WbfVH-iTrepjmYeJpzsKJbjBWvtTOy4BjcxjUe7S0UZvrMIpulv-bH8EJhT-ZnSublufZBtnUa5AB8Eo746zPmoEBhFETx_kGMKtwG11Cj_awV2xlY4P7Teb1UsNYvncPHn7B0gPRq-e3MHeqo0O8GgKcnZb9rR96NpBsLqZ64D--9kbYengtKR25guD1lRRb2ijqkC4aCp7hD7ohE5RjggPoxo5wr8ZQA4-c2HT_uwlpe-QpyY_GdFErAW-eT0sSA0JljDVTsgFFt45CP2Hid2gqRX89-vgBVXjmV9rTZHocGEBg-PgQP0TGeGQMg6RWL9ryzsb0auFRBhiAPkyoPonTNKM_Uh2tSVXKZB27T-dAJRXF4qZ6sFzAgQsrJxphmucPUuFw1RnaFGSM3swf4A8JR6egRegMIHq2qci2uEUyQnfSTYLciNvur5OXXkfYCEb73KaYwzI1I32FUnJ3RsrQPSgS-RhNHSlrfHgf6DjAqa5VNk3u7c4RIreVTxI-ZiGjLJgxHxHUuSIyiKnClH1WrZBZ0yVupkmjcNd08jMbAEIUeP43tMg_Mwl9zjN6kGQdbDbRMNqGw6cIv7_6cCPcT0Uc5e8biHEYdLO6MPsCbH9bOEjVluRY76g8-CNQx188rxm_C1-qmxqbjGlHmebmtA9Gm4WR9RJ4ZBZkuMjMNn-rZv6fuVBtOUxzFUj0RZu4p5yhURxLRDh8OAAYj3gMd1TJ4qXrITd6Qa3VCnaCe9WHJgAEmfHjUiFulqTsv6NIFZiZfr4JysHSSk6qDAwdLDHEfb-XjM7EbS6h-2ehU1wLM6HvXv2PMpq05leZ30XYHpM0m-JGT4iOE-23jcEYba8kx8FpPAEvMaxllEMx-U6cXpaSY7gICbk08mrZJoRwqm1x14JsfWnS40NxypgaEm4Ofz32YP0gzg_96wwS5dPgEU56gS6iQLfdLwyuME7KLcVNGRs0fGDH7hsfBZk1FwBpOQO2o60dsxZTtIHqKnftVrn2fhoc2Q6Cpe3GKPHD3fIzga4_umSTZL_uQg_XTi_01IYRr5dSKQ1GwQVM6ELf1o5Un4YiCZ3qOpjioKWLapQwckdUrKjg95Lxlnq7TkkTlB2C33tjgo_UQ-CLxSYEGR78m0USywEfXi6N0LS2MaDmu0rNY_UweMs9EV0r_y2KqqLy_afFrn3IWn5XcmAaDhI59a_yRtkNYXMnKP3rexMYSdHSY10AVgPO88U-_5nelN5CX4zwNnJsyjD8sno59zEPq1UPvW5q72USgnt3wY4YWSPfkkhNBWr16pKSmTUkuaWtbcP9MQg0uwrHhlQAXcM
>   idsrv.session=3a7192efc6a9690cb33226c0241d91be
>   .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8FAKJpEizERFtUzdjBClgcva9BrL5NevHGMOeN3Y4e-BtNupVoy3JNq-gAf0-xVS97cU9-h7xQXpsv2zJP6nx5leh2DsRxN4uwXPrxiAoJgdfXyTFvhtATpLLRmWPEFnLSH1hD8BTV0U2b2kbBAFl_ny-27_-xoZdV72SVkJcrwAuWCZkNpMcBdGfmNMWXwyL1c8cz684o0oWicEyHvquOdHW_bBpkUrXSQK9b42pln40tPVBlYFLMEgMDKCwWGwYcR8_gx5P0dyobN1R0RHYXFXiwkFNWzz9ZsEpKk9wxWF_Hn7XDNuVV4IiLRwQiVm60njvg15gKUlxPpYQY-8C7oTRPsgZGvSqisVbSlF1EyoLsarDak_Yns21HEQY2AVGs2VxuPidNe6cRdjb5sIRuHUX8kDawttIu8MnrHyLRjaF94Zz-qrCpZfYiHOtfpu7VVg_7HBNusMBOy9xJQLXBftgPamYkCFhnXepQ34RJiM3-1yfQNibj-TaVvSHtt7_lyQdwcnX2MqjxyX3XI7uYqyYT6ela_qBg1C-bTYoiFbiqcv8C_dME9RsBdB_V7q0BtSPvgcHrG5lUJlvksAGyUzo0fQn9dzdEjKU86CaQ_XD349PPznjRe8Tk1E67XqI0CzPhB3RzV_sHdy4Ghfq7MP_WXvOy3hc0mH4TNN03AbB7_aHcIojeHVNh7cyfmcJ-9A6n0jCrSXHxEdf66jjc_VMgxk3nytS_g749s84jAajtxBGnXmqvAnqEYuZZgTAJFMaajq5rrxBU_X_W0DQbErZu3fQU6e_LYrJxAIcXfy4Qh-iynY1flPZBihr0S3qfOxUhrvpB64zq1b3fa9r5edByt9tgBm8KK-wC0b9JjF6kms3rn3YrJIJF00lUG8vZ_MfRr_fU3-e6rG7eQn6YTiQK2ZFfnEo_dzTegfDTJ2fez984jJzJFSC0s47rrb4N2ofoHpAqqqybEWW2UQtURvOU2d5CLRvo32RTI4EBD6bKbv4k92TBpOsZe09ipHmAO9cIBTNfCEkm7AYjv_ZvRrasb6kU7GcrNwRUx1k4fcmDnEeBZZgMbMjWzE6ieJ2miqxOiA3z2vuYcPTMB43vjKjqeAsn5juCx7l4Qo_zdE9UEqLlBSmEOA-UQsdg6m9Dz48QmW0XIxZ1WGVPz2Dbot4zVrgRNg5FzLpUwsvyd3IoLmjSCnvUxNDAXYN2zlUr2ToGVU6O2fYhjmJHRqTVepTebaZ-qjAzex07SR0Oo-LZq0780WKdKIiq5wNNFTVxN30tZuPcfPqd7CBIfZzlkMlyko_RUs18ZiZ8bQaiDLWSbLV-d6nNCO_TSDbLLWkr0gc6BW0ZM8G6BdCVCS6Pb5WlkVGuwejZ5QXSHjPEfqbr06_6FqnrcRts7irjDWnw1GpnT8jkSlwPnLFkcCndm90nWbQ-EKns1qEXQi-m31jdP7m3i83Fyc3pxpcgkTFi0cLfFc1hswdacpBCHPwyDikQ5mszondBiqCHDzZMy635jq8HHREfnJgDNUxkj1WOKnpwCFa6GLWsN1w_U8KpvTEpXM87PRTqIhZW6EfnLzZHuWGpuWCiEATDyyVvgJFIOxQeEHqfXDPPTxl0EuDYCC-9eaw6q0AcgNYbAqlXHWCgqcXshpI1qVu0aQRP_81UT9vk3orUZNZqD-WSA_GHRUTVMedpp-piqDEZ-q35V_NIzhrUwyflpCcTItrhy57-IJbHujRVosl8x6s2A9J_JytTK9y4lqfBe38h6dQtPNOdjhkA_ioWdvWn2KFVLtULnapFScWLm4ew-Gbrxfrmj68JzmsKUOKmm6i0o2Y0JMEg9gsExTh1K3Z_e_DCnfJl3XGgB6Q5rX_qzcvqwyldPn1xJyXealA5KCi38hqsI0wy5-LZhiIUt6PEQX_WNF5wiL9jkT_6-qVfUhlRB87tcqx6YHwdwlYUErsNkrRwZJQrtXxDJoZwEWYy31Ehpi2XVoKTksNGdvHbJcPtFBt7BactgMy6MRu0LVTI8XFhVaG-9LaiHAq9U3c2vblpNjdlBW0nrujZo5MaV5xroyrL3PxZ3j9oj3FzbtgcN_ys5J8FMdhTBAaN5V_YtAWpBH1kP527q_raw1wWdnIvLKQk9hsQJqdldZoKM6mZgyE5_lAWzLs1KN4xwD7Gbz3uQVoaIdIGGsW1iXhB6wJ7WeN9vD6kAJBiI9aHn_iJLmh-QPEWPdMntVipec4UXAACVXPX_QmOvFYxdVhSQp9tdmzpvAfVpQpsbrF29ro0olru0Aimv73wMp4UtIacGSu2T7rHfwkXJ05o9IDuUnjOC9oXMhxLvz_dBwjHeHt_B3BvBQ-XNSEQra0fD0MzJ3GBRqK1vUWRJQzaUmfZF5aE39az8qoRZBAYKFrAzqE8Y2IsEK6UhrJj4QuJ03l_skguhXuraLyH-IO6fnRqF5lZQgO81RIZKDvRlhNrcGJsM6yOotUXXTpVz9xjOtn1rMO1woO0up8kr16vlcRKp_TUh_VqDvV-AbY93ZYBUuvVUiLonGaOK7V3X7uqJGFsh0f27hy7CKYyjviPLo9eEs_oMsjh34cLEzDEPSZtgdqbv6_82ruVRA6S5wKWr6v3HluBVjJP7Q8iBJbLzFfl85ihIjj04hYZQmBUx0E0a646NVETdibYC7zcmdtGOUb045Nifb3A
> ```

**IdentityServer Config :**

```
public static class IdentityServerConfig
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
                  new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile()
    };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
             new Client
            {
                   ClientId = "angular_spa",
                    ClientName = "Angular 4 Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"openid", "profile", "api1"},
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/auth-callback", "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html"},
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/"},
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200"},
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Angular Configurations :

```
export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority: 'http://localhost:44380/',
    client_id: 'angular_spa',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
  };
}
```

Kindly let me know what could have gone wrong

**Edit:** What I've found so far is

1. Even with another Angular oidc client `angular-auth-oidc-client`, I am stuck in the same error
2. With JS client,  (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/6_JavaScriptClient), it is working as expected. but since we have Angular as front end, I implemented the JS sample in Angular by including the required JS library and to my surprise, I am facing the same issue
3. When I copied the URL and pasted in another browser, the `call-back` component is invoked. So it seems like there is something wrong in Header & Cookie.
   Here is the complete data of the request I took from Fiddler

   GET http://localhost:4200/call-back?code=7bc6c3d343067f2ede3ed86268e3622bb909cb8df5d75d2f223b335bd75b730c&scope=openid%20profile%20api1&state=86215491d41a4c3c83d52007edf372cd&session_state=ibjjr0YMpGp_UZ1ezmUMusoAIpht25ySKfq8hoCKHXQ.e7f8f959a82f09b830a9635911c0b9f3 HTTP/1.1

   Host: localhost:4200
   Connection: keep-alive
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
   Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
   Sec-Fetch-Site: none
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

   Cookie:

   .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xkdte50z5pg=CfDJ8FAKJpEizERFtUzdjBClgcvmHhFjLJ4WDhku77bzpIxGI20-....

   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
   Connection: close

This is what I see in the browser

[image]

Comment: Check the error in Logs.txt.

Comment: @aaron The logs(src/Logs/Logs.txt) found in aspboilerplate does not give any clue on why this error occurs

Comment: The most common causes with this error are either 'Request Too Long' or redirect_uri_mismatch. Could you please mention more details regarding error you are getting. 
Also are you using any Kubernetes setup for deployment?

Comment: @AparnaGadgil It is still in dev (Visual Studio). I am not seeing any error any where in browser console or in application logs. It is not even hitting the "auth-callback" angular component. Kindly look into my edit.

Comment: Do you use angulr cli?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I am using visual studio code for Angular development running the required Angular commands in terminal

Comment: do you have routing mapping auth-callback -> AuthCallbackComponent ?

Comment: Also in bad request is this there any body?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat, Yes the routing mapping is available. That is why it invokes the call-back component when I opened the URL in separate browser (Edit #3) and I do not see any body in the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198276/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-gopi).

Comment: If you exactly followed those articles, try to contact them via twitter or provided contact methods. Most of the authors will respond to questions.

Comment: can you put your code sample on github and provide repo link where it can be reproduced

Comment: Did you try to do login in Chrome Incognito mode?

Comment: dat cookie tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason Angular do not accept that much data(Cookie) as part of Header. Though this works with JS client, I am not sure why this happens with Angular.

During initial phase of development, for some reason, I have commented out the following lines in `Account/ExternalController.cs` of IdentityServer

```
// delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

When this line is commented out, there will be additional Cookie that will be posted to Angular during the call back.

Uncommented the above line will delete the temporary Cookie and there will be less header data during the call back and it invokes the respective Angular call back component and sets the bearer token.

**Clarifications Required**

1. If someone can share why Angular isn't accepting large header data while it works perfectly with JS client.
2. Though Angular says Bad request, I was not able to find from where(which layer in Angular) this error occur is thrown. I did not even see a single line of error from which I could get some hint on reason for the error(large header data)

If some expert could share their experience on the above couple of points, it will be really helpful to understand how Angular works.

> If for any reason, you cannot limit the header size, then increase the
>   node's --max-http-header-size. Kindly refer
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667786/2922388 on how to do it.

Comment: It is not Angular throwing exception, It is your development web server. What server is actually serving your Angular app on port 4200?

Comment: @Nenad I am using visual studio code to run the the Angular application. And My understanding is it is not running on a server but on browser. Please correct me if I am run

Comment: That explains part of the confusion around this question. Redirect from IdentityServer back to you app (from `localhost:44380` to `localhost:4200`) first hits web server. Web server then serves Angular JavaScript app to the browser. App is then executed and during execution it analysis URL on which it was served and switches the view.
Your Visual Studio Code debug button is configured to execute a command, probably `ng serve`, which under the hood uses `webpack-dev-server` to serve files to the browser. That dev server is throwing `400 Bad Request` upon redirect.

Comment: @Nenad Thanks for helping me understand that while using Visual studio code, Angular runs on a web server called as "webpack-dev-server". I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Gopi you just add the reference to actual solution shouldn't you mark answer from me as accepted

Comment: @jitender W.r.t to this question, the actual solution is to remove the Cookies rather than increasing the header size. I added the reference because, if there is someone who searches for larger header size issue, it will be helpful. Usually in SO, people tend to look at he marked answer. Hence I linked it.

Answer (score 6):

As you already find out the exact problem is of header limit and solve it by limiting cookie size but limiting cookie size may not be a solution everytime.Main reason behind why angular doesn't accept large header data is bcs angular use node serve `webpack-dev-server` and there is limit on header size in node js you can find related issue bellow

[ng serve fails to serve pages when large cookies are present](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14801)

[400 Bad request due to Node limiting header size to 8kB](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1711)

[Update npm run to fix hpe_header_overflow in recent nodejs versions](https://github.com/getredash/redash/pull/3732)

[Make HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE configurable](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24692)

So instead of using `ng serve` using command

```
node --max-http-header-size=16385 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

should be the solution to your problem

Comment: In fact, I tried to increase the --max-http-header-size to 80000 (a random selection) using the node.js command prompt, yet when running Angular using ng serve it still throw'ed the same error. So my understanding was the header was not set to given value. I was not able to find any command on how to check the current --max-http-header-size. So I dropped the idea of setting the --max-http-header-size and looked for other solution. Do you know any command to check the --max-http-header-size ?

Comment: default max header size for node is 8k in latest versions [Since that is a compile-time constant, you would have to use a custom-compiled version of Node to set that constant larger.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24189407/5621827) 
So instead of using `ng serve` directly setting the header size and then serve should work

Comment: Yes, I understood that the default header size is 8 KB, hence I raised to 80 KB using the node js command prompt. But looks like it did not work.

Comment: Currently occupied in another work, will try and let you know with in today. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It worked like charm..! Thanks a lot! But when deploying on UAT or PROD, we need to increase the header size for the respective web servers(like IIS) correct?

Comment: i think yes [check this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097727/5621827)

Answer (score 1):

Just try with few fixes. 
 First - `RedirectUris` seems suspicious, since it contains more than one value, - according to the http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html - declaring this as a `List<string>` could be the source of the issues.

Next, following the example of server side config https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs

```
    new Client
    {
       ...
        RequireClientSecret = false,
        RequireConsent = false,

        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
        AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api" },

        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse

    }
```

Let's assume that `AllowedScopes` should include mandatory `email` scope, 
then `GetIdentityResources()` needs last fix:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
        };
    }
```

Since SPA code is out of scope here, for proper flow implementation please follow the examples:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/,

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mixed something up in *routes* or *redirect_url* configuration?

Based on configuration of the client and server you posted, `redirect_url` should be:

> http://localhost:4200/auth-callback`

Yet, in the screenshot path is `/call-back`, not `/auth-callback`.

I would check if configurations (client and server) and Angular router all have same path `/auth-callback` configured.